# Intercept made by a line between two concentric circles

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, circles, analytic-geometry

Let $$x^2+y^2-9=4r^2\enspace (r=1,2,3)$$ be $3$ concentric cirlces. Prove that the intercept made by line $$3x+4y+15=0$$ between any two cirlces is same.

I thought of calculating the intercept between any two cirlces and then prove it that they are numerically same. But, it would be too long. So, can someone suggest me an elegant method for proving it? Just give me the working lines.

Comment: The circles don't intersect, the line isn't vertical or horizontal... What is this "intercept" that can be the same?  Is this referring to the line *segment* between any two circles and suggesting that it is of equal length between any two circles?

Comment: Do you mean that the segment lengths on the line between circles $1$ and $2$ and circles $2$ and $3$ are the same?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Let $L$ cut $C_1$, $C_2$, and $C_3$ at $A$, $B(–5, 0)$, and $C$ respectively. $POJ$ is the line passing through the origin and is normal to line $L$.

$\triangle OJB$ is similar to $\triangle OP’P$. Therefore, $OJ = 3k$, $JB = 4k$ and $OB = 5k$; for some $k$.

$OB = 5$ units implies $k = 1$. Therefore, $OJ = 3$, $JB = 4$ and $OB = 5$.

Applying Pythagoras theorem to $\triangle OJA$, $\triangle OJB$ and  $\triangle OJC$, we have $AJ = 2$, $AB = 2$ and then $BC = 2$.

Answer (score 0):

$3(x+5)=-4y\iff\dfrac{x+5}4=\dfrac y{-3}=t$(say)

$\implies x=4t-3,y=-3t$

$$x^2+y^2=4r^2+9\implies(4t-3)^2+(-3t)^2=4r^2+9\iff25t^2-24t-4r^2=0$$

$(t_1-t_2)^2=(t_1+t_2)^2-4t_1t_2=\dfrac{576+400r^2}{625}$

If $(x_1,y_1);(x_2,y_2)$ be the intersections

$$D_r^2=(x_1-y_1)^2+(x_2-y_2)^2=25(t_1-t_2)^2=\dfrac{576+400r^2}{25}$$

Put $r=1,2,3$